# Is there a way to tell VSCode where the .vscode folder is?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to have .vscode inside another folder. But the settings are reset when I do that and it creates a  new folder. I searched it on the internet and in the settings but I found nothing. It would be even better if there was a way to change the settings only for my device and safe them in appdata or something, but I think that doesn't work for workspace settings.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, I'd say creating a **symlink** or a **shortcut** to the **.vscode directory** would be perhaps would be the easiest solution to your question.

Another solution be as proposed [here](https://www.iditect.com/how-to/58587621.html):

What I did - after installing Visual Studio Code for the first time, I checked the documentation and added at the end of 'Target' field of editor's shortcut the following (there's a space before the two dashes):

```
 --extensions-dir="DRIVELETTER:\VSCODE\extensions"
 --user-data-dir="DRIVELETTER:\VSCODE\settings"
```

where DRIVERLETTER and VSCODE are the corresponding drive and directory where Visual Studio Code is installed. So mine looks like this:

```
"D:\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" --extensions-dir="D:\Microsoft VS Code\extensions"
```

Here is for the user data directory:

```
"D:\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" --user-data-dir="D:\Microsoft VS Code\settings"
```

Accessing the 'Target' field is done by right-clicking the shortcut and choosing 'Properties'

Comment: Yeah that's a good idea but I'm talking about the workspace settings, they are safed in `workspace-folder\.vscode\settings.json`